# Is it possible to destroy a road that I previously placed?

Tags: actraiser-renaissance

Is it possible to destroy a road that I previously placed?

I didn't understand how roads and fort placement worked relative to where monsters spawn. Leaving a gaping hole in my defenses and there's an open road path straight to my temple. Can't build forts on this path due to terrain I guess.

[image: bad road]

Comment: This is not Actraiser, or at least not the SNES one from the 90s... is this a re-release of some sort?

Comment: Remake. https://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/actraiser-renaissance-switch/